# Android. Hide status bar without delay

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-actionbar, statusbar

I am trying to hide the status bar. This is my code:

```
 window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
 actionBar?.hide()
```

The status bar is hidden, but the behavior is not quite expected.
Suppose I have 2 activities. Activity A and Activity B. Activity A has a green status bar, and activity B needs to hide the status bar. In Activity B, I call the code to hide the status of the bar in onCreate() before performing the setContentView(). As a result, when switching to activity B, the green status bar is displayed for the first few seconds, and only after it is hidden. I need the status bar to be hidden immediately upon transition to activity B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User this in you Java Files **OnCreate** Method
`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity B, you just need to set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your MaterialToolbaror CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but in my Activity B there is only androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

Comment: Both `MaterialToolbaror ` and `Toolbar ` are the same. You can try it.

Comment: The status bar is still displayed for a few seconds